# How to remove stopwords from list?

Tags: python, list, stop-words

I have been struggling with a code because I haven't been able to remove or replace the stopwords of a list. I know I might be overlooking something but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is my list:

> result = [' COLOMBIA Y LA NUEVA REVOLUCIÓN INDUSTRIAL Propuestas del
> Foco de Tecnologías Convergentes e Industrias Volumen COLOMBIA Artista
> Federico Uribe Propuestas del Foco de Tecnologías Convergentes e
> Industrias Tomo COLOMBIA Y LA NUEVA REVOLUCIÓN INDUSTRIAL
> Vicepresidencia de la República de Colombia Ministerio de Ciencia
> Tecnología e Innovación Elías D Niño Ruiz Jean Paul Allain José
> Alejandro Montoya Juan Luis Mejía Arango Markus Eisenhauer María del
> Pilar Noriega E Mauricio Arroyave Franco Mónica Álvarez Láinez Nora
> Cadavid Giraldo Olga L Quintero Montoya Orlando Ayala Raimundo Abello
> Tim Osswald Primera edición ISBN Impreso ISBN digital DOI https doi
> org vdyc Colección Misión Internacional de Sabios Título del volumen
> Colombia y la nueva revolución industrial Preparación editorial
> Universidad EAFIT Universidad del Norte Carrera No sur Dirección de
> Investigación Desarrollo e Innovación Tel Medellín Km Vía Puerto
> Colombia Área Metropolitana de Barranquilla e mail publicaciones eafit
> edu co Tel e mail dip uninorte edu co Corrección de textos y
> coordinación editorial Cristian Suárez Giraldo y Óscar Caicedo Alarcón
> Diseño de la colección y cubierta leonardofernandezsuarez com
> Diagramación Ana Milena Gómez Correa Medellín Colombia Prohibida la
> reproducción total o parcial por cualquier medio sin la autorización
> escrita del titular de los derechos patrimoniales
> __________________________________ Colombia y la nueva revolución industrial Elías D Niño Ruiz et al Medellín Colombia ', ' Yordan
> Mantilla uno de sus líderes señaló que actualmente se desarrollan en
> el mercado eléctrico y en sus proyectos de automatización requieren
> nuevas tecnologías de las comunicaciones p p Enfocamos el desarrollo
> del concepto de ciudades inteligentes creando soluciones para la
> cuantificación de variables ambientales Otro proyecto es T Cyborg que
> busca integrar el análisis de los sonidos de las ciudades para
> entender cómo percibe e interpreta su ciudad una persona ciega explicó
> Mantilla p p Insegroup tiene una unidad de negocio que busca
> desarrollar los pilotos de sus proyectos en Cúcuta para poner en
> práctica su oferta de servicios y ofrecerla a mediano plazo a nivel
> mundial p p strong Dentro de la validación del T Cyborg Latinoamérica
> y Centroamérica mostraron tener un potencial enorme para acceder a esa
> tecnología la cual es de punta e innovadora indicó el empresario
> strong p p Camilo Puello cofundador de Just Sapiens convirtió una idea
> de negocio digital nacida en en una empresa Hoy su iniciativa se ha
> vendido a nivel regional y nacional p p En un par de meses buscamos
> vender la idea a nivel internacional en el departamento hemos vendido
> el servicio a abogados y a entidades públicas En el país hemos llegado
> a Neiva Santa Marta y Bogotá explicó Puello p p A través del clúster
> se están desarrollando estrategias para enfocar a las empresas en
> segmentos de mercado con baja ocupación donde la región con su
> portafolio de servicio puede apoyar en la generación de alto valor
> agregado con soluciones TIC p p strong Vitrina internacional strong p
> p Una delegación de cerca de empresas colombianas en las que no se
> incluía empresas nortesantandereanas generó en el Mobile World
> Congress llevado a cabo en Barcelona ventas por cerca de millones de
> euros y expectativas de negocio de cerca de millones de euros p p
> Procolombia reseñó esta información en su página web donde se aseguró
> que Colombia despuntó en Barcelona siendo la delegación
> Latinoamericana más grande p p La presidenta de Procolombia Flavia
> Santoro manifestó que el Mobile World Congress fue una gran
> oportunidad para mostrarle al mundo el valor agregado de las
> industrias del país ']

Here are the codes I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(result)):
    for j in stop_words:
        if j in result[i]:
            result[i] = result[i].replace(j, '')
```

and:

```
new_list=[]

for w in result:
    w = w.lower()
    if w not in stop_words:
        new_list.append(w)
        

print("\n Palabras filtradas:",new_list)
```

but both of them show me this when I printed it:

> ['colombia y la nueva revolución industrial pr  fc  tcgí cvrg  ir vl
> colombia ar frc urb pr  fc  tcgí cvrg  ir t colombia y la nueva
> revolución industrial vcrc   rúbc  cb mr  cc tcgí  icó elí d nñ rz j p
> al jé ajr m j l mjí arg mrk er mrí  pr nrg e mrc arrv frc móc álrz láz
> nr cv gl olg l qr m or a r ab t owl pr có isbn ir isbn gl doi   rg vc
> cccó mó ircl  sb tí  vl cb    rvlcó rl prcó rl uvr eafit uvr  nr crr n
> r dccó  ivgcó drrl  icó t mlí k ví pr cb ár mr  brrql  l bcc f  c t  l
> r  c crrccó    crcó rl cr sárz gl  ócr cc arcó dñ   cccó  cbr rrzrz c
> dgrcó a m góz crr mlí cb prb  rrccó l  rcl r qr    rzcó cr  r   rc rl
> __________________________________ cb    rvlcó rl elí d nñ rz  l mlí cb mr  cc tcgí  icó  mó ircl  sb isbn eccó cb eccó  rrl cb drrl cífc
> clógc cb i nñ rz e d ii nrg e mrí  pr  iii mjí arg j l  iv ab l r  v
> tí vi sr c  c uvr ef cr crl bbc l ecrrí vlg
> ___________________________________ t colombia y la nueva revolución industrial bgí bcí  m ab slv rr crr cr sr frc  p r u ezb h mb trr eb
> mr rl eñ mc e frc lgr wj a grá pv cc bác   ec mé wr lrr crr crz d brá
> srg hrc frc r nb a mrí r a a j c vl cc scl  drrl h c eq c frr p crr a
> mrí arj sr vcr alr slg w m e u s d frc j sc h k sg n cr  sr cc   v
> sl j m a crr nb mñz ib mg frc rlf lá jrg rl ajr j ergí sb j bv crr ag
> wlk ', '   rg cc r  cr cgí c flr  q r cífc  vlcr  fc    r   pr  rr  c
> cr á q í rc c c cc c  cb méxc arg brl  c gráfc r  cbrcó rcl   ár ir
> cb f ebrcó r  r  frcó  wos cb    rvlcó rl gráfc p r lí  rbj r f ec brl
> cb  lí c   rvlcó cb    rvlcó rl ccó  bcc cb   rc  rgr   u   rg vg
> jrcc   bbrí    có  c   bcc céc   rccó   cc rz   rgr    vcó l fr lens
> rg gr b     c b   céc  r ccr  c   rccó cé c   gcó   cgí é  fr   uz  fr
> fcó  úr  vc   r c rbj céc vc  cb   rcl rfr   ác  fc vr tb e r r   rccó
> cb  í  b c  brg  rccó  cc r     vc r   g   rccó   rccó    e  r c  cl
> á  rvc l áx    vgr  í rc cc    r c   éx tb ic   rccó céc   gcó l
> prcj prccó   crccó  cc  r   prccó   gcó   f ebrcó r  r  frcó  l rv gbl
> arccó  r g cr rcv l  rcl  fccó   vgcó   có  gr c  cc  c  có  c  r  fc
> rá   gcó  cc   crczcó     r   ccó e  cb  lí c   rvlcó rc vr r  e    cr
> fl l frcó   r   ccó crb  rccó   r   gcó  rcó  cc  cb s c  gr  v  có
> rcó clógc   r   cfr  vró  cc  cgí  c     vlcr icó  rcó clógc r    r
> clcc c   r cb cg c r r   c l r clcc d fr     c bl   cr fcrr  rvc r
> l  r c   r   rc  r    d or  fl   á   r   v  rcó clógc   gr r  q cfc c
> ñ   r kz l tb r c v  ár c cbrgr ccó   b r   c c l r  rcr r     c  gú
> cfr  mr  crc ir  tr   cr ñ   r m rr    bc rcv crb c      í  r   prc ir
> br ncl mcrc e v  rcó   r  r cl   fr  g cróc bé  í   p d   c mtic r   v
> r  g c cr v  g á     el v  có c  gbrl  á l  rvé     c     t   r r  p
> fc  có cb    rvlcó rl    vz   gr r  jr c  c cb   rcv gbl  í el    p
> críc   r  bj v  r có  r  r u   r á gr   r  crrr  brc  ccó c  gr cñí
> sgú mcrc  p cb c    rc   r grg    rbjr   gr r e frcó rc  rfxó r   c
> rzr  c  rá fcr  cv  act  í d   cb  crrr brc rgl brc   gr r   p  cr  r
> rcó   cr rcv   cr céc ivró  có cc  cgí l r cb rr  rvé   ec cl  có
> dane vr  acti  á  bl  tb arcó  cgí r ñ  r  cb pr tcgí ncl gr p mcr
> ifrrcr cbrgr ccó   b prc ir   c rbóc iró d r l drbcó bg  igc rfcl bckc
> f t  kz cb  lí c   rvlcó  l  q l   vró l cl  c  lr   tb tb prccó  cr r
> fccó   cv acti  cb t  có t   ic  ccó rr er cr  vgcó  rrl clógc e gbrl
> ipsfl l rvc   r hl  clíc ong cc  grc rl tl l    l cop  f t  oct cálc
> oct cfr rvl cfr rc scr rcv c   tcgí cvrg nbic  ir  cb   c cóc l c fcr
> rvc  dane   b  r    cc   cí  í el jrcc    r   rccó   bcr á rc c  ár
> fc  rcó c  l   v  gr r grg   e  cr fcrr  cr  cb    rvlcó rl g bcr rc
> frác cróc  óc   q écrc qr  q  c  víc  r rlq  rlq pr  c  cr rvc  clr
> rrl   frác rc    cv rl cífc  écc l tb c  frcó ']

Comment: what's inside your `stop_words`?

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it like this :-**

```
[word for word in result if word not in stopwords]
```

Comment: please REMOVE the image, and replace it with text instead

Comment: please refer to [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to provide a good answer on a post.

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split your text into tokens ("tokenize"), because the `for w in result` does not iterate over words but characters!

So it removes the characters that are stopwords.

As @Mahrkeenerh commented, you can try:

```
for w in result.split(): # For simple tokenization
    w = w.lower()
    if w not in stop_words:
        new_list.append(w)
```

Comment: or: `for w in result.split()`

Comment: The problem is that if I split my text in words with 'Tokenize', then I can not distinguish which words are from a specific document, and I need that. :(